# Prove that the (recursive) sum of the digits of any number multiplied by 9 is 9

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

Prove that $$\sum_{digits}...\sum_{digits}9a = 9, a∈ℕ$$

Examples

```
9x2 = 18 -> 1+8 = 9

9x21 = 189 -> 1+8+9 = 18 -> 1+8 = 9

9x543 = 4887 -> 4+8+8+7 = 27 -> 2+7 = 9 

9x87,523 = 787,707 -> 7+8+7+7+0+7 = 36 -> 3+6 = 9 

9x98,745,632,584 = 888,710,693,256 -> 8+8+8+7+1+0+6+9+3+2+5+6 = 63 -> 6+3 = 9
```

Comment: I don't know how to mathematically express "sum of the digits", but I gave it a shot

Comment: See "casting  out nines" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines  Congratulations on finding this!  Just because it has been done before, does not diminish your accomplishment.

Comment: The question you're asking can be rephrased as "prove that the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of any (positive) multiple of $9$ is $9$".

Comment: Much more concise and precise @Omnomnomnom.

Comment: @owninggreendragsdude perhaps, but the real goal there was to give you the appropriate term to google.